# Adnroid-TV tcp ADB & USB-ports unusable

Tags: android, usb, adb

I want to use ADB on my Adnroid-TV over Wifi. It works like a charm, but there is main downside: although just using ADB over TCP/Wifi, the USB-Ports seem to get unusable. This especially means, that time-shift on the TV is not usable, as no USB-storage is detected anymore.
Is there a way to use ADB over Wifi and have the USB ports still functional? Can I configure the ADB server? Is there another way/app to control the TV via Wifi without loosing USB-functionality?

Regards
SEB